# Chrome display incorrect font family?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-family

It is said that for each site, the browser will select the first font in the `font-family` list which is installed, but I found that my `chrome` browser doesn't work properly.

For example, when open the `github` README page, the `font-family` of the style sheet for `<code>` block is `SFMono-Regular,Consolas,Liberation Mono,Menlo,Courier,monospace`. My ubuntu has installed `Consolas` and `Menlo`, and the default monospace font family of my browser is `DejaVu Sans Mono`, but the browser still displays a font which is not monospace.

Is it because of my misunderstanding of style sheet or because of the `chrome` browser?

Comment: Can you share a code of how you have added the font family in your code so it will be easier for us to help you?

Comment: @StefanJoseph The question is not about code the asker has written. It is about a discrepancy with browsers, and the asker is using the GitHub page as a reference. Read the question.